# One-boxing for sites with large logos overflows in chat transcript

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design

When you paste a bare link to a Stack Exchange site in chat, it gets oneboxed as a clickable image of the site's logo, like so:

[image: meta stack overflow onebox]

When the site's logo is enormous, like [CS Theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/)'s, it overflows if the width of the chat area is less than the width of the logo. This causes the image to [hang over into the side bar area](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4155938#4155938), and go off the page if the window is small enough:

[image: cs theory logo overflowing]

This of course doesn't look so good. Typically images that are one-boxed get scaled down to fit nicely in the chat window; the same size restrictions should be applied to one-boxed site logos as well.

Comment: Always up for BBQ.  Where's my invite?

Comment: The invite info was posted on Secret Meta. Sorry.

Comment: @casperOne - I read invite as wife, now i feel guilt.

Comment: O_o how the heck do you get "invite" and "wife" mixed up...

Comment: So how would you read 'invite my wife'?

Comment: Invite here while you're at it...

Comment: ok; I'll add some CSS restrictions to that tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is rather excessive. It will be fixed for any future occurrences. Entirely my bad... wait, er, no: blame Jin for making that logo atypically huge!

(just kidding, blame me)

Comment: Much better! Great :)